# How to select a file but allow file system navigation with FileFilter?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I want to display a FileChooser to the user where he can only choose .csv files, but he can navigate through the filesystem to find the .csv he wants.
Reading through http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html
it seems as if you either give the user the option to err and choose a directory or you must limit him to see only .csv files. Is there no more user-friendly way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JFileChooser has quite a lot of options. Maybe, I'm missing something, but the default [fileSelectionMode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileSelectionMode%28int%29) should only let the user pick files, not directories. Add a [choosableFileFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#addChoosableFileFilter%28javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter%29) that accepts .csv files and directories and you should be done.

Other useful settings are [multiSelectionEnabled](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setMultiSelectionEnabled%28boolean%29) and [acceptAllFileFilterUsed](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed%28boolean%29).

Comment: the way you describe it the user will not be able to describe the file system to find the .csv. If you do the way described by oracle the user could navigate the file system but also choose folders (instead of .csv files).

Comment: Describe the file system? You probably meant traverse... Make your FileFilter also accept directories. That should fix it.

Comment: I refer to the FS Oracle's refers to. Here's the point: I don't want to accept directories because if I do the user can choose directories, which are not .csv (.csv are files and not directories).

Comment: @simpatico: just set fileSelectionMode to FILES_ONLY, and it will not let user choose directorites but still allow him to browse directories for .csv files.

Comment: @Override
            public boolean accept(File f) {
                return f.isDirectory() || f.getName().endsWith(".csv");
            }